# Automatically initialise a custom jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm in the process of creating a new accordion plugin using the [jQuery Boilerplate](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate) as a starting point.

I'm a jQuery novice when it comes to building plugins but it currently seems to be working great.

The user can initialize the plugin the traditional way ( `$('elem').plugin({"option":"value"})` ) or inline, on the element itself ( `<div data-plugin='{"option":"value"}'>` ).

The issue is the plugin needs to be called outside of the plugin code, inside a `document ready` for each method ( For example - `$('elem').plugin()` ).

What I want to do with this plugin is have the plugin automatically initialize on set element(s) within the markup, such as `<div data-accordion>`. I've tried wrapping the element in a jQuery wrapper,inside a `document ready` but it doesn't seem to work.

The code for the boilerplate is:

```
;( function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    "use strict";

        var pluginName = "defaultPluginName",
            defaults = {
                propertyName: "value"
            };

        function Plugin ( element, options ) {
            this.element = element;
            this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
            this._defaults = defaults;
            this._name = pluginName;
            this.init();
        }

        $.extend( Plugin.prototype, {
            init: function() {
                this.yourOtherFunction( "jQuery Boilerplate" );
            },
            yourOtherFunction: function( text ) {
                $( this.element ).text( text );
            }
        } );

        $.fn[ pluginName ] = function( options ) {
            return this.each( function() {
                if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                    $.data( this, "plugin_" +
                        pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
                }
            } );
        };

} )( jQuery, window, document );
```

Hope someone out there can help.

Thanks :)

Comment: _inside a document ready for each method_ - what do you mean?

Comment: There are many of these already online, any reason you're writing your own instead of using one of them?

Comment: @Maximus Just a use case scenario really - If the user wanted to use the plugin on their website they would include it in `$(document).ready(function() {  //here  });`


@NathanielFlick I've decided to have a go building my own as lots out there aren't built for css3 transitions and don't have the options I regularly use (destroy the plugin at a certain, user defined screen size for example)

Comment: If they put `$('elem').plugin({"option":"value"}) ` in the ready function, it will be inialized and shoul work property

Comment: @Maximus Sorry if I've not not been clear in my original post but, the plugin I've created already works by adding it to a ready function. Ideally I want the plugin to auto-initialize when it detects the required element in the markup, that I set inside the plugin code, (`<div data-accordion>` for example), without the need for any extra external js. If a user chooses to run the plugin, only using the inline data method in the page markup (`<div data-plugin='{"option":"value"}'>`) the plugin currently still needs to be added to a ready function, which I'd rather not have. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @ChickenDinner, so your plugin should parse the DOM and find nodes where it can be attached to